# std::map iterate and delete valgrind errors

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a simple program which deletes the items in a std::map while iterating over the Map. If I am not wrong forward iterators are not invalidated by erase in a map. But valgrind throws invalid read errors. Can someone explain why.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> SourceMap;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SourceMap sourceMap;
    sourceMap["item1"] = 1;
    sourceMap["item2"] = 2;
    sourceMap["item3"] = 3;
    sourceMap["item4"] = 4;


    for(SourceMap::const_iterator it=sourceMap.begin(); it != sourceMap.end(); ++it)
    {
        sourceMap.erase(it->first);
    }
}
```

**Valgrind errors:**

```
==31703== Invalid read of size 8
==31703==    at 0x3851069E60: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==31703==    by 0x4013D6: std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, int> >::operator++() (stl_tree.h:259)
==31703==    by 0x40106B: main (map_iterator.cpp:14)
==31703==  Address 0x4c2c0b8 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==31703==    at 0x4A0545F: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==31703==    by 0x402821: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, int> >*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:95)
==31703==    by 0x402103: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, int> >*) (stl_tree.h:363)
==31703==    by 0x4017D0: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, int> >*) (stl_tree.h:384)
==31703==    by 0x4027AB: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, int> >) (stl_tree.h:1348)
==31703==    by 0x401FF2: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, int> >) (stl_tree.h:1388)
==31703==    by 0x4016A7: std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::erase(std::string const&) (stl_tree.h:1374)
==31703==    by 0x40141C: std::map<std::string, int, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::erase(std::string const&) (stl_map.h:582)
==31703==    by 0x40105C: main (map_iterator.cpp:16)
==31703==
==31703==
==31703== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31703==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31703==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 312 bytes allocated
==31703==
==31703== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: `If I am not wrong forward iterators are not invalidated by erase in a map`. [You are wrong](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase). You can use the return value of `erase` for an iterator to the element past the element that was just erased. In this particular case, you can just use `map::clear()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been discussed to death. You must not use invalid iterators. Write it like this:

```
for(SourceMap::const_iterator it = sourceMap.begin();
    it != sourceMap.end();  /* no hoist */
   /* no increment */ )
{
    sourceMap.erase(it++);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
// as before
{
    it = sourceMap.erase(it);
}
```

Alternatively yet (since you don't have any conditions on the erasing):

```
sourceMap.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do something awfully wrong:

While iterating through the map you erase the key the current iterator is pointing to. Doing so, you invalidate that iterator.

map::erase(iterator->first) has the same effect as map::erase(iterator), but the latter is more appropriate and efficient.

Note: See the answer of Kerrek SB, too